# Why does clang automatically add "cstdio.h"?

Tags: c++, g++, clang

Assuming I have the code snippet like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("%d",5);
}
```

It compiles and runs normally on my Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) compiler, however it fails on gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8), saying it doesn't recognize "printf" function. Professors at my Uni use the latter and today they said that my program doesn't work.

My question is - why does clang (run by g++ namefile.cpp on OS X 10.9) include "cstdio.h" automatically in this case?

PS. I am aware there are cin and cout streams in C++, and that would solve the problem, but my question is more theoretical and for future purposes of automatic includes.

Comment: Why not? It's not forbidden. Your program is ill formed since you rely on non-standard "feature". You should use correct headers every time you use something and not rely on some compiler include it for you.

Comment: Yes, _ill-formed_ is the keyword.

Comment: Thank you. The "ill-formed" program is just an example. Do you have any suggestions on what can I do when simply forgetting to include _the_ file and it still works without giving me a single notice/warning?

Comment: Yes, Szymon: Test in the same environment you'll be graded on.

Comment: It's `<cstdio>` or `<stdio.h>`, not `"cstdio.h"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard C++ headers are allowed to include any other standard headers. Each implementation has the option to decide which headers get included by which others. You've included iostream, and that's allowed to include cstdio, but it's also allowed not to. Your version of Clang and your instructor's version of GCC have evidently exercised the option differently.

Best practice dictates that you explicitly include the headers you need; don't count on you implementation to implicitly include headers you haven't mentioned. It's liable to change from one release to another, and it affects portability.

Comment: Formally, it's not implementation defined, although it does depend on the implementation. When something is implementation defined the implementation must document what it does.

Comment: thank you. I simply forgot to include cstdio, however it was still working - this is the problem when writing code to be used by any other compilers.

Comment: Indeed, Szymon. Your instructor probably warned you at the beginning of the term that your programs would be tested on your school's computers, and that it's your responsibility to ensure they run there, regardless of where you developed them. I know we made such warnings in my classes.